# Response.Redirect doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, response

I am wondering why my Response.Redirect doesn't work. So basically, I read the files in my folder, or exactly the index.html. When I find it i redirect to it .

```
 foreach (System.IO.FileInfo thefile in fiArr)
        {
            if (thefile.Name == "index.html")
            {
                //Response.Redirect(path + "/index.html", false);
                Response.Redirect("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Folder//" + ((LinkButton)sender).ID,     false);
            }
        }
```

I am just wondering why this doesn't redirect anywhere.

Comment: Yeah when I redirect to google.com it works for example.

Comment: Well what *does* happen? Bear in mind that you're passing in `false` for the "end the response" argument - is there a reason for that? Have you validated that it actually gets into your `if` block?

Comment: So what should I use to redirect to this index.html ? Because the process.start will work only on local and not on iis ...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes It is actually going in the loop, and with the true at the end of the response doesnt change either .

Comment: Why are you sending it to your local drive ? why not use something like http://localhost/Folder/, plus one more thing, don't you have to mention the file name at the end of the path or do you have index.html as default document for the folder in IIS ?

Comment: @Emged: Not into the *loop* - into the *if* block.

Comment: make sure you are getting correct path using this: Response.Write("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Folder//" + ((LinkButton)sender).ID);   I doubt whether you are getting page name.

Comment: Ok i fixed the page name, i forgot to uncomment the right one . So now its going to something like this : c://inetpub//wwwroot//Folder//myfolder//Index.html. But it's still not redirecting, but it's the good path.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes in the if. I checked everything and the path too.

Comment: @Emged: Okay, so next is Habib.OSU's comment - you should be redirecting to a *URL*, not a local filename. I'd have expected the redirect to occur, but to just give an error. If you look using Fiddler, what's in the response?

Comment: That was the good one , redirecting to a URL . Thank you very much Jon and Habib  !

Comment: Can someone of you post an answer I can accept to close this please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Response.Redirect only support to redirect to a URL beginning with "http://", a virtual folder located on same server or a file in same folder.

You could add your folder with files as a virtual folder in the server and redirect to the virtual location of the file.

Another approach can be to use javascript to do a client side redirect to the file instead.